# Possible to break statement in foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach

I have two tables (`user`,`user_group`). Where user table contains

```
------------+-------------+------------------+
|  user_id  |  user_name  |  user_group(id)  |
------------+-------------+------------------+
```

and `user_group` table contains

```
+-----------------+-------------------+
|  user_group_id  |  user_group_name  |
+-----------------+-------------------+
```

Now I try to join them without using `JOIN` query. To solve this problem I have used double `foreach()` loop, but no result returns. I can't use `break` statement. How can I get the desired result using a loop? The desired result would be:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
|  user_id  |  user_name  |  user_group_name  |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
```

What I have so far:

```
public function user_get_item()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $results=$this->db->get()->result_array();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user_group');
    $group_data=$this->db->get()->result_array();
    foreach($results as $v_results)
    {
        foreach($group_data as $v_group_data)
        {
            if($v_results['user_group']==$v_group_data['user_group_id'])
            {
               $v_results['user_group']=$v_group_data['user_group_name'];
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is changing the group id identifier by the group name in the current row if they match. So, replace:

```
$results['user_group']=$v_group_data['user_group_name'];
```

by:

```
$v_results['user_group']=$v_group_data['user_group_name'];
```

Anyway, what's wrong with joins? Making SQL queries will be always faster than a polynomic loop.

Comment: After replacing - $v_results... that provide same result. But thanks for your query suggestion @Peregring-lk

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you would have this:

```
Array(
    0 => Array(
            [user_id] => 1,
            [user_name] => John Doe,
            [user_group] => 200
         ),
    1 => Array(
            [user_id] => 2,
            [user_name] => Jane Doe,
            [user_group] => 100
    )
)
```

And:

```
Array(
    0 => Array(
            [user_group_id] => 100,
            [user_group_name] => Admin
    ),
    1 => Array(
            [user_group_id] => 200,
            [user_group_name] => Web User
    )
)
```

So make a new array for the group so it looks like this (ID as key, Name as value):

```
Array(
    [100] => Admin,
    [200] => Web User
)
```

To do that:

```
public function getUserGroups()
{
    $rows = array();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user_group');
    $group_data=$this->db->get()->result_array();
    foreach($group_data as $results)
    {
        $rows[$results['user_group_id']] = $results['user_group_name'];
    }

    return $rows;
}
```

Then you just assign in the other method:

```
public function userGetItem()
{
    # Get all the user groups
    $groupData = $this->getUserGroups();
    # Get your original user list
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $results=$this->db->get()->result_array();
    $row = array();
    foreach($results as $users) {
        $row[] = array(
            'user_id' => $users['user_id'],
            'user_name' => $users['user_name'],
            # Here you assign the group name from the user groups array
            'user_group_name' => $groupData[$users['user_group']]
        );
    }

    return $row;
}
```

Anyway, I think `JOIN` would be faster/better, but this should get you the results you are looking for, though I have not tested it, it should be close.